# How do you do wudhu when praying in a car?

Tags: salat, wudu, travelling

Sometimes I find myself on the road at prayer time and would love nothing more to be able to pray on time and therefore not wanting to delay the prayer. However If you are praying in the car how would you go about doing wudhu

Comment: why you cannot quit car?

Comment: You are not supposed to pray in a car as you may stop at any time any where and pray and perform wudu' as it is prescribed in fact praying on a horse, donkey or camel is only supported for optional prayers. The situation in an airplane or ship might be quit different.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question. You would do wudu the same way you normally do it. You would find a place to stop the car, take some water and do wudu. You may carry water bottles with you in the car, or you may look for a gas-station etc. In Muslim countries you can often easily find roadside mosques which would have the relevant facilities.