# What verses should I recite when I pray and how can I keep up prayers while driving a truck?

Tags: salat, practical-islam

What verses should I recite when I pray? And what are some ways to keep up prayers while driving a truck? I currently read few pages of the Qur'an every night. And I'm a over the road team driver.

Comment: Well i wouldn't recommend you to pray while driving (for your safty in first place) but it would be acceptable to some extent, some scholars accept it only for nafl/sunna/optioanl prayers others may allow it also for fard/farz/obligatory prayers. But if you reach the distance of qassr and you would be considered as a traveler you could shorten prayers and pray at least dohr and 'asr and/or maghrib and 'isha at the same time!

Comment: See also http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27459/praying-in-the-car

Answer (score 2):

Recite what you learned, if you know only "Al-Fatiha" then you can repeat it.

> https://islamqa.info/en/5410
>
> But if a person is able to recite part of al-Faatihah only, he should
> recite that which he is able to recite. And he has to repeat what he
> can recite well (i.e., so that the total number of what he recites
> will be seven verses, equivalent to the number of verses in
> al-Faatihah).
>
> Ibn Qudaamah said:
>
> It may be sufficient for him to say alhamdu-Lillaah (praise be to
> Allaah), laa ilaaha ill-Allaah (there is no god but Allaah) and
> Allaahu akbar (Allaah is most great), because the Prophet (peace and
> blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whatever you know of Qur’aan,
> recite it, otherwise praise Allaah, proclaim His Oneness and magnify
> Him.”  (Narrated by Abu Dawood)

If you a traveling you are allowed to combine your prayers even shorten them.

> Ruling
>
> https://islamqa.info/en/105109
>
> Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah (may Allaah have mercy on him) said in Majmoo’ al-Fataawa (22/293):
>
> The reason for shortening prayers is travelling only, and it is not
> permissible in situations other than travelling. As for joining
> prayers, the reason for it is need and excuses, so if a person needs
> to he may join both shortened and full-length prayers whilst
> travelling, and he may join prayers when it is raining and so on, or
> because of sickness and the like, and for other reasons, because the
> purpose behind it is to spare the ummah hardship. End quote.

I'm not sure about shorthen and combined prayers. But from what i know ( please correct me if i'm wrong) you could combine Dhuhr and Asr (praying Dhuhr just before the time of Asr) and combining Maghrib and Isha ( praying Maghrib just before the time for Isha).

Comment: If you are traveling you could shorten all 4 rak'a (fard/farz) prayers to 2 rak'a this is also called qassr/qasr. And combing does mean for example you either pray the dhuhr later (at the beginning the time of 'Asr or just before) or the 'Asr earlier (when dhuhr time is already runining for a while or at the end of it)